# Spinner not working in custom Dialog - why?

Tags: android, dialog, spinner, custom-adapter, customdialog

I am trying to use a android Spinner in a Custom dialog, but when I tap on the Spinner the list with items opens and you can tap on them and the view closes, but none of the items gets selected. When I use the exact same code in a normal Fragment it works fine.

And since I found nothing helpful anywhere, is there something I need to know when using the spinner in a Dialog ?

**CustomDialog Class:**

```
public SelectionDialog(Activity context, ArrayAdapter<T> arrayAdapter, List<T> objects) {
    super(context);
    this.activity = context;
    this.arrayAdapter = arrayAdapter;
    this.objects = objects;
}



@SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_selection,null);

    setContentView(view);

    BodyMenuCard parentCard = view.findViewById(R.id.parentCard);
    parentCard.setHeader(header);

    TextView textView = parentCard.getCardBody().findViewById(R.id.bodyText);
    textView.setText(description);

    yesBtn = parentCard.getCardBody().findViewById(R.id.btn_yes);

    //spinner = parentCard.getCardBody().findViewById(R.id.employeeSpinner);
    spinner = view.findViewById(R.id.employeeSpinner);
    spinnerHandler = new EmployeeSpinnerHandler(getContext(), spinner, (List<Employee>) 
    toggleYesBtn(false);


    if (iconRessoruce != -1) parentCard.setIcon(iconRessoruce);
    if (backgroundColor != -1) parentCard.setCircleColor(backgroundColor);

    if (successfullCallback != null) yesBtn.setOnClickListener((v -> successfullCallback.onClick(this)));
    if (abbortCalllback != null) {
        parentCard.getCardBody().findViewById(R.id.btn_no).setOnClickListener((v -> abbortCalllback.onClick(this)));
    } else {
        parentCard.getCardBody().findViewById(R.id.btn_no).setOnClickListener(v -> this.dismiss());
    }
}
```

**EmployeeSpinnerAdapter**

```
public class EmployeeSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Employee> {

private Map<String, ColorStateList> employeeColors;

private List<Employee> employees;

private RandomMaterialColor randomColor;

public EmployeeSpinnerAdapter(Context context, List<Employee> employees) {
    super(context, R.layout.employee_spinner, employees);
    setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.employee_spinner);
    this.employees = employees;
    this.employeeColors = new HashMap<>();
}

private class ViewHolder {

    private GradientDrawable background;
    private TextView header;
    private TablePart idField;

    private ViewHolder(View view) {
        if (randomColor == null) randomColor = new RandomMaterialColor(view.getResources(), view.getContext());
        ImageView iv = view.findViewById(R.id.icon_view);
        background = (GradientDrawable) iv.getBackground().mutate();
        header = view.findViewById(R.id.header);
        idField = view.findViewById(R.id.description);
    }

    private void populate(Employee employee) {
        header.setText(employee.getName());
        idField.update(employee.getId());
        ColorStateList color = employeeColors.getOrDefault(employee.getId(), ColorStateList.valueOf(randomColor.getMatColor("A700")));
        background.setColor(color);
    }

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return employees.size();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    return obtainView(position, convertView, parent);
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    return obtainView(position, convertView, parent);
}

private View obtainView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.employee_spinner, parent, false);
        convertView.setTag(new ViewHolder(convertView));
    }
    ViewHolder vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    vh.populate(employees.get(position));
    return convertView;
}
}
```

**EmployeeSpinnerHandler**
The purpose of the class is to have exacly the same code handling the Spinner inside a dialog and outside, to find the mistake.

```
public class EmployeeSpinnerHandler {

private Context context;

private Spinner spinner;

private EmployeeSpinnerAdapter adapter;

private List<Employee> employees;

public EmployeeSpinnerHandler(Context context, Spinner spinner, List<Employee> employees) {
    this.context = context;
    this.spinner = spinner;
    this.employees = employees;

    setUp();
}

private void setUp() {

    adapter = new EmployeeSpinnerAdapter(getContext(), employees);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            FancyToast.makeText(getContext(), "selected: " + employees.get(position).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG, FancyToast.SUCCESS, true).show();
            //toggleYesBtn(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            //toggleYesBtn(false);
            FancyToast.makeText(getContext(), "selected: none", Toast.LENGTH_LONG, FancyToast.SUCCESS, true).show();
        }
    });

}

public void updateObjects(List<Employee> employees) {
    this.employees.clear();
    this.employees.addAll(employees);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

**The Spinner inside the normal Fragment**

```
spinner = view.findViewById(R.id.employeeSpinner);
    EmployeeSpinnerHandler spinnerHandler = new EmployeeSpinnerHandler(getContext(), spinner, objects);
```

**Notice:** In boath cases the date gets fetched from a REST-Api, but it still only works in the normal Fragment.

And now the problem is, if I use the EmployeeSpinnerHandler on a Spinner located in a normal Fragment it works, but if I am using the Spinner in the selection dialog, you can click the spinner and the items show up, but they arent selectable (see in the images).

Images:

[Custom Dialog with Spinner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cra54.jpg)

[Popup from Spinner in custom Dialog, were you can see the data is present, but if clicked it only closes the popup view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HAFg.jpg)

[Spinner Working inside the Normal Fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbWqD.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapter allow single focus view make `android:focusable="false"` for all other items`android:focusable="true"` for your TextView which holds the title it will work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be missing a visual update in case the below code return an item :
            FancyToast.makeText(getContext(), "selected: " + employees.get(position).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG, FancyToast.SUCCESS, true).show();

In that case i would recommend adding 
   spinner.setSelection(position)

Comment: But the problem is that this method never gets called in the custom dialog.